# Shiny server - CSS

Tags: css, r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have a question regarding how to apply colours and layout to all the apps in shiny.
I have all my apps saved here:

- **/srv/shiny-server/all_apps/**

And I have three apps:

- **/srv/shiny-server/all_apps/app_1/**
- **/srv/shiny-server/all_apps/app_2/**
- **/srv/shiny-server/all_apps/app_3/**

I know that if I need to include a CSS file for the **app_1**, I need to create inside **app_1** a `www` folder and save the CSS file inside.

But I don't know where I need to save the CSS/HTML files to create a nice interface where the user can select the app that they want. Right now if I go to the following page:

- **/srv/shiny-server/all_apps/**

I have an ugly first page to select one of the three apps (see below).

## Index of /all_apps/

- [app_1/](http://ukshinyserver:3838/all_apps/app_1/)
- [app_2/](http://ukshinyserver:3838/all_apps/app_2/)
- [app_3/](http://ukshinyserver:3838/all_apps/app_3/)

Could anyone help?

Thanks,

Julen

Comment: If I understand you right, you just want to create a start page with links to your apps?

Comment: yes, I basically want to know where I can save the HTML/CSS to create a start page.

Answer (score 1):

Then you just need to save HTML/CSS files for a start page in **/srv/shiny-server/all_apps** :)

It's important to name the HTML file "index.html", otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked.  I was using different names...

Comment: glad it helped! would you mark my answer as accepted then?